# How do I clear screen in IronPython console?

Tags: console, ironpython

When we work with a regular Windows command prompt we can clear the screen by typing `cls` command.

How I can do the same in IronPython console (ipy)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import System.Console
System.Console.Clear()
```

Comment: It definitely works and that why you earn +1. I just wonder if there's a shorter version.  Of course, I can wrap it inside my own function.

Comment: IPython (http://ipython.scipy.org/moin/) has 'cls' alias predefined, but I don't know whether it works with IronPython.

Answer (score 2):

Use `!` to run a shell command:

```
!clear 
!cls
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this command to clear screen:

```
reset
```